# Can I map entity field names to alias column names in TypeORM?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am in the process of migrating from Rails to NestJs with TypeORM.
For historical reasons, table names and column names in Rails are `snaked_cased` - I don't want to copy this nuisance to our NestJs/React side.

Can I create entity fields in NestJS (typeorm) called `firstName` but are mapped to a column named `first_name` in my DB?

My table

```sql
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                      system_users                       |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| id          | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| first_name  | varchar(100) |                            |
| last_name   | varcahr(100) |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

My User Entity Class

```js
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity({ name: 'system_users' })
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 255 })
  first_name: string; // <-- I WANT THIS TO BE firstName (camelCased)

  @Column({ length: 255 })
  last_name: string;  // <-- I WANT THIS TO BE lastName (camelCased)
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I finally found what I was looking for in the documentation. The `@Column` attribute receives many properties, one of them is `name` which can define the column name associated with the field.

My updated entity:

```js
@Entity({ name: 'system_users' })
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 255, name: "first_name" })
  firstName: string; 

  @Column({ length: 255, name: "last_name" })
  lastName: string; 
}
```

Comment: This was 100% identical to what I was looking as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else comes across this issue, know that TypeORM supports [naming strategies](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/naming-strategy.md).
And there is even a package for a [snake case naming strategy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-naming-strategies)