# How to remove prefix from returned columns in typeorm querybuilder

Tags: mysql, sql, typeorm

I set following querybuilder in typeorm.

```
const sql = this.attendanceRepository
      .createQueryBuilder("attendance")
      .leftJoin("attendance.child", "child")
      .select("attendance")
      .addSelect("CONCAT_WS(' ', child.firstName, child.middleName, child.lastName)", "childName")
      .addSelect("child.class")
      .where("attendance.id= :id", { id: id})
      .getRawOne()
      const Result = await sql
```

That querybuilder produces following `SQL`

```
SELECT `attendance`.`id` AS `attendance_id`, `attendance`.`child_id` AS `attendance_child_id`,
`attendance`.`attendance_cd` AS `attendance_attendance_cd`, `attendance`.`come_home_time` AS `attendance_come_home_time`, `attendance`.`late_time` AS `attendance_late_time`, `attendance`.`memo` AS `attendance_memo`, `attendance`.`created_at` AS `attendance_created_at`,
`attendance`.`updated_at` AS `attendance_updated_at`, `attendance`.`deleted_at` AS `attendance_deleted_at`, `child`.`class` AS `child_class`, 
CONCAT_WS(' ', `child`.`first_name`, `child`.`middle_name`, `child`.`last_name`) AS `childName` 

FROM `attendances` `attendance` 
LEFT JOIN `children` `child` 
ON `child`.`id`=`attendance`.`child_id` 
WHERE ( `attendance`.`id`= ? ) 
AND ( `attendance`.`deleted_at` IS NULL )
```

It returned folloiwng data.

```
{
    "attendance_id": 2,
    "attendance_child_id": 4,
    "attendance_attendance_cd": 3,
    "attendance_come_home_time": "11:50:00",
    "attendance_late_time": "23:40:00",
    "attendance_memo": "test",
    "attendance_created_at": "2020-10-16T13:33:00.053Z",
    "attendance_updated_at": "2020-10-19T10:34:55.000Z",
    "attendance_deleted_at": null,
    "child_class": "S",
    "childName": "hikaru hikaru"
}
```

But my desired result is folloiwng

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "child_id": 4,
    "attendance_cd": 3,
    "come_home_time": "11:50:00",
    "late_time": "23:40:00",
    "memo": "test",
    "created_at": "2020-10-16T13:33:00.053Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-19T10:34:55.000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "child_class": "S",
    "childName": "hikaru hikaru"
}
```

How can I remove prefix `attendance_` ?

If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know typeorm, but does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311203/can-i-map-entity-field-names-to-alias-column-names-in-typeorm

Comment: No. It's not helped.

Answer (score 5):

please use .select("attendance.*")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no official solution from TypeOrm Issue created on Aug 2020 on Github https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3031

But you could map the result and filter the prefix follow answer for that

[Change key name in JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452014/change-key-name-in-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `getOne` instead `getRawOne` and it will auto mapped.

```
const sql = this.attendanceRepository
  .createQueryBuilder("attendance")
  .leftJoin("attendance.child", "child")
  .select("attendance")
  .addSelect("CONCAT_WS(' ', child.firstName, child.middleName, child.lastName)", "childName")
  .addSelect("child.class")
  .where("attendance.id= :id", { id: id})
  .getOne();

  const Result = await sql;
```

I hope it'll help you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you find a solution but I hope this one could help anybody with the same issue.
You should just use getOne / getMany to have the result will be automapped with your entity. So instead of getting this one **entity**_id for instance, you'll only get id.

Answer (score 0):

I've remove the prefix by adding `.select('*')`.

You don't need `.select("attendance")` since `attendanceRepository` which is the same table.